# PHP How to set variable between 2 numbers

Tags: php

Having trouble, can anyone tell me how I properly set my variable between 2 numbers? I gave it a shot, but this is not right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> if/else </title>
</head>

    <body>

    <?php
        $randinterger = rand(10,100));

if ($randinterger <= 25) {
    echo ($randinterger);
    echo ("This is less that 25");
} elseif (26 < $randinterger <= 50) {
    echo ($randinterger);
    echo ("This is between 25 and 50");
} elseif (50 < $randinterger <= 75) {
    echo ($randinterger);
    echo ("This is between 50 and 75");
} else (75 < $randinterger <= 100) {
    echo ($randinterger);
    echo ("This is between 75 and 100");
}

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run this code, and you'll see that you have  a syntax error. Also, what is not right?

Comment: I  think want you want is to compare and check if a variable's value is between 2 number. `26 < $randinterger <= 5` -> should be come `$randinterget > 26 && $randinteger <=5`. And same for other condition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare numbers like that. See corrected code below.

```
<?php
        $randinterger = rand(10,100));

if ($randinterger <= 25) {
    echo ($randinterger);
    echo ("This is less that 25");
} elseif (26 < $randinterger && $randinterger <= 50) {
    echo ($randinterger);
    echo ("This is between 25 and 50");
} elseif (50 < $randinterger && $randinterger <= 75) {
    echo ($randinterger);
    echo ("This is between 50 and 75");
} else (75 < $randinterger && $randinterger <= 100) {
    echo ($randinterger);
    echo ("This is between 75 and 100");
}

    ?>
```

you have to split the conditions. What you want to know if is `randinteger` is lower than x **AND** greater than Y.